# matmul input operand 1 has amismatch in its core dimension error 0 when trying to run sklearn linear regression

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

The error is ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?)(size 8758 is different from 1)

```py
import os
import pickle
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
import sys
import time

def BowtoArray(bow):
    bow = bow.split(",") #the bag of words will always be a string of numbers separated by commas
    final = [int(i) for i in bow]
    final = np.array(final)
    return(final)

TruthModel = pickle.load(open("TruthAI.p","rb"))
BiasModel = pickle.load(open("BiasAI.p","rb"))
BOW = sys.argv[1] #the bag of words is passed into terminal

BOW = BowtoArray(BOW)

BOW = BOW.reshape(-1,1)
Score = [TruthModel.predict(BOW), BiasModel.predict(BOW)]

f = open("pyTest.txt", "w")
f.write(str(Score))
f.close()


sys.exit()
```